# Java abstract class extends two classes

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have got a similar line digging up a OpenSource Project:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<A extends ParentClass1,
    B extends ParentClass2>
```

Can you please tell me what actually it means? I think java does not support multiple inheritance so what actually we are doing here? And what is `A` and `B` here? :S

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **A and B are just place holders** which can be **replaced with any class that extends ParentClass1 and ParentClass2 respectively**. You can pass arguments in angular brakets(<>) when you create object of this class. These arguments will be substituted for A and B by the compiler during compilation.

The above code does not indicate multiple inheritance. Please read [generics](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596009208/16dot-collections-and-generics-data-structures/in_generics_comma_lextendsr_means_lexten) in detail to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

it's generic type
look here for generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the content within `<>`, then you see its only

```
abstract class AbstractClass
```

that means, the class is not extending any classes at all.

```
abstract class AbstractClass<A extends ParentClass1,
    B extends ParentClass2>
```

essentially means, the class would like to declare 2 generics A and B, and force its type. That means, it want the implementer of the class to supply the 2 classes which extends `ParentClass1` and `ParentClass2` respectively.

Please see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for more clarification